# Space after semicolon

Tags: math-mode, spacing

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Mutual Information}
\begin{align}
I(X;Y)&=H\left( {X} \right) -H\left( {X\mid Y} \right)\\
I(X{;}Y)&=H\left( {X} \right) -H\left( {X\mid Y} \right)
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In my opinion, the second equation is right but I prefer to write the first. Is it possible automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to do it; but of course this changes *all* spacing around the semicolon in math mode. I left the second row for comparison.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% punctuation is type 6
\mathcode`;=\numexpr\mathcode`;-"6000

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Mutual Information}

\begin{align}
I(X;Y)&=H(X) - H(X\mid Y)\\
I(X{;}Y)&=H(X) - H(X\mid Y)
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that your usage of `\left` and `\right` is wrong: there's no need for them here; also bracing the inner expressions is redundant.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know my usage of \left and \right  it´s not necessary. I think there is a problem with the space after comma and semicolon in math mode. Your answer is a possible solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @jpayansomet By default, the semicolon is considered a punctuation symbol, like the comma, so it's followed by a thin space. The trick in my answer changes the setting, making the semicolon into an ordinary symbol

Comment: {@greg}, the same problem happens with the symbol \mid. It is normal to use it like 'conditional probability', for example. It is possible to use the same trick? How?

Comment: @jpayansomet You can use `|`, but I don't think the result is good and I'd much prefer `\mid`.

Comment: but is it possible to eliminate the space around \mid?

Comment: @jpayansomet Why? `|` produces the same symbol, without spacing.

Comment: because i have written four hundred pages with \mid.

Comment: @jpayansomet `\renewcommand{\mid}{|}`

Comment: The simplest solution is the best solution. Thanks again.